# Finding all nine items hidden items

Tags: gone-home

I feel like I've combed through every inch of the house. Collected 23 of Sam's audio logs and also seen the ending. The only thing left seems to be the items. There are nine slots in the items window. But right now I have only six.

- Katie's Passport
- Katie's boarding pass
- House key
- Sam's safe combination
- Basement key
- Attic key

Where can I find the missing three? Or do they even exist?

Answer (score 2):

In [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/232430/discussions/2/364041776196354289/) post, the developer confirmed that they designed the inventory screen to have space for 9 items before they completed the game, which actually only holds 6 or 7 items.

From that post, the developer says:

> Yep, you're right about the 7th item thing-- for at least one frame of
> computation, you have both halves of the combo in your inventory. Then
> when the game detects that you have both of them, it removes them and
> replaces them with the completed combo. So that extra slot needs to be
> there to support it. That said, we designed the UI before we knew how
> many inventory items we'd have in the game-- we just knew we'd need to
> not have more than 9 ;)